# CakeResque plugin not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I am trying to use CakeResque plugin in cakephp 2.4 and follow all installation instruction as per link

http://kamisama.me/2012/10/16/background-jobs-with-php-and-resque-part-6-integration-into-cakephp/

When I fire command

```
cake CakeResque.CakeResque start
```

Getting error

> Error: Class CakeResqueShell could not be loaded.

Any help appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load the CakeResque plugin into your CakePHP app first.

In your app/Config/bootstrap.php, make sure that the plugin is loaded with

```
CakePlugin::load('CakeResque' => array('bootstrap' => true));
```

or with

```
CakePlugin::loadAll('CakeResque' => array('bootstrap' => true));
```

the `bootstrap` key is needed to load resque settings. (you can also specify a path to your own bootstrap file instead of `true`)

If that still does not work, maybe you're not using the "right" cake shell. You seems to use

```
cake CakeResque.CakeResque start
```

Just make sure that the `cake` command in your environment is the one inside you app. Test that:

```
cd path-to/app/Console
./cake CakeResque.CakeResque start
```

It it still doesn't work, you're welcome to report your issue in [CakeResque](https://github.com/kamisama/Cake-Resque) issues tracker.

Comment: ,Thank you for response,My code is working now but your answer is more explanatory and your tutorial is nice.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the only way to workout, you will have to configure `Fresque` to work with `php-resque-Ex.`

Comment: @Nilesh,Thanks for response,But Fresque is only command line tool for making interfacing with php-resque more easier and more friendly.

Comment: @Nilesh Without Fresque tools,we can use CakeResque shell commands to manage workers and etc.