# CakeResque - Class 'Resque' not found in app/Plugin/CakeResque/Lib/CakeResque.php on line 82

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.7

http://cakeresque.kamisama.me/install#install

As instructed in the link above, I've been trying to install CakeResque plugin to CakePHP 2.7.10 with no luck. I'm getting the following error.

> Fatal error: Class 'Resque' not found in /path/to/app/Plugin/CakeResque/Lib/CakeResque.php on line 82

I tried

```
php /usr/local/bin/composer.phar update
```

and

```
/usr/bin/composer self-update
```

and did not forget to add this to core.php.

```
require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/Vendor/autoload.php';
```

I found the exactly same question at Stack Overflow, but mine is different because adding autoloader to core.php didn't work.

I use CentOS 6.7, php 5.6.15.

Comment: Was [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19091311/cakeresque-plugin-not-working) the question you referred to?

Comment: The same question I referred is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333958/cakeresque-resque-not-found-in-app-plugin-cakeresque-lib-cakeresque-php-on).

Comment: Ensure you installed `php-resque-ex` or just `php-resque`

Comment: Have the same issue, did you fix it eventually?

Comment: I decided not to bother with Composer. I installed CakeResque into app/Plugin directory by hand and then it worked fine.